# ARIMA and SARIMAX predicting the data well but Forecasting straight/uniform results

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have time series data which is distributed for 12 days with a interval of 5 minutes, I am trying to forecast future values with ARIMA, SARIMAX, AUTO ARIMA,

I'm new to time series, i followed most of the procedures based on tutorials in Kaggle/Github but when i do the same for my data the values are coming uniformly,

I have tried with different orders, seasonal orders but not getting the required result, and also unable to figure out where i'm going wrong,

Any help and suggestions would be thankful

ARIMA, SARIMAX and AUTO ARIMA, all the models give a very high AIC values, i.e [70000 - 150000]

Here is the code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(data, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())



import statsmodels.api as sm


mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data,
                                order=(1,0,0),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 24),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

The data is stationary[confirmed with ADF test], Trend is uniform [not straight (freq = 7)] hence i kept the d value as 0.

I have tried with various values of p,q, and m.

Comment: what are p,d,q, and m?

Comment: p = AR fatcor, q = MA factor, d = difference, m  = interval for seasonal ARIMA model,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same values for ARIMA forecasts in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842872/same-values-for-arima-forecasts-in-r)

Comment: Is my historical data affecting the model?, I have 12 day data in a 5 minute interval, around 3700 records in total! Can't we forecast values based on 12 day data?